# How to send json format after make base64 encoded image

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, base64

Here i am converting two images for base64 ,this one working fine after that i want make one json format, so  i am trying like this but i no able to get answer. i am getting error like **"message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: floor_image is not defined",** how to solve this issue and send json format

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').click(function(){

var filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad").files;
if (filesSelected.length > 0) {
  var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];

  var fileReader = new FileReader();

  fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
 var floor_image = fileLoadedEvent.target.result; // <--- data: base64
 console.log("Converted Base64 version 1 " + floor_image); // i am getting answer here
  }
  fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
}


var filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad1").files;
if (filesSelected.length > 0) {
  var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];

  var fileReader = new FileReader();

  fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
 var property_image = fileLoadedEvent.target.result; // <--- data: base64
 //console.log("Converted Base64 version 2 " + property_image);  // i am getting answer here
  }
  fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
}

var json = {
 "FloorImage" :floor_image,
 "PropertyImage" : property_image
}

console.log(json);


});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="idname">
<input id="inputFileToLoad" type="file" /><br><br>
<input id="inputFileToLoad1" type="file" />
<br><br><br><br>

<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have the `floor_image` in the global scope. Try to write `var floor_image;` outside of the method, then set `floor_image` to your result as you do, but remove the `var` keyword in the method. The same goes for `property_image` and `json`

Like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var json={FloorImage:"not loaded yet",PropertyImage:"not loaded yet"};
  var floor_image;
  var property_image;
$('#submit').click(function(){


var filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad").files;
if (filesSelected.length > 0) {
  var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];

  var fileReader = new FileReader();

  fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
 floor_image = fileLoadedEvent.target.result; 
    json.FloorImage=floor_image;
  }
  fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
}


var filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad1").files;
if (filesSelected.length > 0) {
  var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];
  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
 property_image = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
    json.PropertyImage=property_image;
  }
  fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
}

console.log(json); // you are logging the json before the images are loaded, because this code is executed before the code inside onLoad.


});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="idname">
<input id="inputFileToLoad" type="file" /><br><br>
<input id="inputFileToLoad1" type="file" />
<br><br><br><br>

<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

**Scenario**
Try to load the `FloorImage` first, you will see the text: `"not loaded yet"` in both properties of the `json`-object. Then try to load the `PropertyImage`, and you will se the base64 of the `FloorImage` inside your `json`-object, but the text `"not loaded yet"` on the PropertyImage. This is because the images are not finished loading when you print the json-object. However the images are there after the `onload`-method is done.

Comment: Mr John can u make fiddle

Comment: @subikshanM I have added a snippet now. Try to load `FloorImage` first, you will see the text: `"not loaded yet"`. Then try to load `PropertyImage`, and you will se the base64 of the `FloorImage` inside your `json`-object, but the text `"not loaded yet"` on the `PropertyImage`. This is because the images are not finished loading before you print the `json`-object

Comment: I tried ir Snippet i getting {
  "FloorImage": "not loaded yet",
  "PropertyImage": "not loaded yet"
},

Comment: @subikshanM Try doing the scenario I wrote in the comment above

Comment: You have it after you load the images. You could call a function inside the onload, passing the json-object as a parameter, and then do what you want to do. I am not sure how to explain it differently.

Comment: Ok i got i have one question pls,before base 64 encode the i want to do image convertion, suppose user select jpef,gif image means i want convert the png format after that i want to convert base 64 string

Comment: You can add an extra property to your json, storing the file extention like so: `json={FloorImage:{FileExtention:"png", base64:"your base 64 string"}}` and do the same for PropertyImage

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems:

1. `floor_image` and `property_image` are in local scope. You should
   move them to `click` function's scope
2. `onload` is just a callback. It means that `json` object may
   be created before files have loaded. You should only create it after
   2 `onload` functions called (for example, use flag to determine
   `onload` called or not, and only create `json` when both of them are
   `true`)